# Marklogic snippet return incomplete result set

Tags: javascript, search, marklogic-10

I am looking out method for getting all matches in snippet.but I am getting incomplete set of result.
I have set maxSnippetChars,maxMatches,perMatchTokens values to max.
Structure of documents is an array of objects and I want path all matching object's property(Synopsis) which satisfy matching criteria. 
can you please help me out.
 I am using below code:-

````
.where(jsearch.byExample({"$query":{Synopsis:{"$word":"word","$case-sensitive":false}}}))
.slice(0, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
 .map({
   snippet: {

   maxSnippetChars:Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
     maxMatches:Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
   perMatchTokens: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
  }, extract: {paths: ['/ID','/FullName']}
  } 
  )
 .result() ```
````

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to configure the snippet generator properties, you can adjust the build-in mapper order in the **jsearch** pipeline as below:

```
  .where(jsearch.byExample({synopsis: {$word: 'word'}}))
  .slice(0, 15)
  .map({extract: {paths: ['/ID','/FullName']}},
      {snippet: {
        maxSnippetChars: 150,
        maxMatches: 4,
        perMatchTokens: 30
  }})
  .result()
```

- Notice the logic is to extract the xpath properties first then apply the build-in snippet generator.
- The caveat of using the blanket `***_INTEGER`: Doing so may return fewer match snippet text by setting it too small or negate the constraint by setting it too big.

> Generally speaking, below query should return the desired extracted paths and snippet without losing any text:

```
  .where(jsearch.byExample({synopsis: {$word: 'word'}}))
  .slice(0, 15)
  .map({extract: {paths: ['/ID','/FullName']}}
  .result()
```

Comment: thanks for your help Fiona chen .I am using snippet to exactly locate match text in array.Matching text is in array of objects and by mentioning  in extract path I am getting complete array rather than just matched elements; Will configure snippet generator as you mentioned :)